# Access a constant in unnamed scoped enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Consider following code snippet:

```
enum class { TEN=10 };
```

How to access a constant declared in unnamed scoped enum?

I know about phrase from Standard (7.2/2)

> The optional identifier shall not be omitted in the declaration of a scoped enumeration.

But if we cannot use it (TEN constant), why this allowed (no compile error)? 
Confirmation link: http://ideone.com/updQWS

Comment: You can't'. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: With `enum class { TEN = 10 } e;` you can still do `e = decltype(e)::TEN;`

Comment: @juanchopanza I want to understand why obviously useless design does not result in a compilation error.

Comment: @alexolut: There are tons of useless things you *can* write. But it would make the language vastly more complex if you were to add mandatory diagnostics for anything that isn't useful on a high level. Compilers may offer warnings as a matter of QoI, but it's not the language's purpose to disallow any bad programming. It's main purpose is to *allow* good programming.

Comment: The quote clearly says that this is not allowed. Looks like the compiler is accepting some invalid C++. Clang gives me an error: "scoped enumeration requires a name".

Comment: VS2013 also gives an error with this declaration, but g++ 4.6.4 (MinGW) does not, so I think @JosephMansfield is right.